# Are there scales that record weight continuously?

Tags: chemical-biology

I would like to monitor the weight of something continuously (e.g. once a minute) and access the data easily via a phone app.  Is there something like that?

There are numerous options for similar devices if you want to measure ambient temperature and humidity (e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/SensorPush-Wireless-Thermometer-Hygrometer-Android/dp/B01AEQ9X9I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AEQ9X9I)).

But all my searching for scales with similar functionality have failed.  I've found many lab scales and kitchen scales, and body weight scales.  Only the body weight scales interact with apps on your phone, but they do not record continuously.

If you know of one, or just have better google-fu than me and can suggest a more precise search term, any pointers would be appreciated.

[ In case you are curious about the application (which is not chemistry), I want to measure water transpiration and evaporation in a bonsai tree, and measuring the weight of the tree in its pot is my proxy for water usage.  This has worked well with manual measurements, but I want to go to the next level. ]

Comment: Try “data logging balance”. I had a colleague who used to insist that fish have scales, chemists have balances.

Comment: The load cells that are used in many cheaper balances certainly put out a weight-dependent voltage continuously, so it should be eminently possible to do this.  I know folks who have made their own data logging balance by hooking up such a load cell to an Arduino or Raspberry Pi...

Comment: @edv Thanks for the clarification. I didn't know if a balance implied the old-fashioned mechanical balance.

Comment: @CurtF. I have an arduino lying around.  Project time, maybe!

Comment: You could use a normal balance and then record the display with the smartphone camera. I did that once for a project, it's not fancy, but quite simple.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti  Clever!  And hilarious.  Nothing will stop you, obviously.  I want to do this continuously, and outside, so I can't dedicate my phone to it.  ;)

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti No, not at all sarcastic.  I like the idea.  It's perfect for a short term solution.  Sorry if my tone suggested otherwise.

Comment: Oh, ok alright then, sorry. Good luck with your experiment :-)